# Which IPTC field to use for the lead image in a set?

Tags: metadata

Is there an IPTC field which allows me to specify that an image is the 'lead image' from a set?  Not necessarily the first image, but more like a manually chosen cover-image for an album?

Comment: Have you reviewed the schema(http://www.iptc.org/site/Photo_Metadata/IPTC_Core_&_Extension/)? What did you find?

Comment: I have skimmed through it but there is too much to read it all. I found OriginalTransmissionReference and Job ID fields which indicate that an image is part of a set.  I tried searching for terms like lead/main/cover, but I did not find anything to indicate an image is the most important one from a set.

Comment: Before I answer that question, can you tell me what application will you be using to show the 'album' or 'cover' image? For example, are you asking how to select an image to be the cover image in a Windows folder? v/r B. Shaw

Comment: Do you need it to be IPTC as opposed to another type of metadata?

Comment: @BShaw The application is one I am developing myself.

Comment: @mattdm I can instruct photographers on what IPTC fields to use, but it must be IPTC. Anything else would require a major change in their workflow.

Comment: See if this schema works for you - http://cv.iptc.org/newscodes/role1/

Comment: See if this schema works for you - http://cv.iptc.org/newscodes/role1/.     In it, you'll find which item should be considered 'main'.  Also, the schema includes a 'preview' attribute, as well as, a 'thumbnail' attribute.

Comment: @BShaw can you point me to somewhere that explains how to use NewsML / NewsCodes with a set of images? Is it embedded in the image's IPTC metadata?